# Want to display all infowindow for all marker at a time

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating custom infowindow for all marker because i want to display user icon in marker. I want to display all marker at a time open on marker in map but I am not able to do this.

This is my code.

```
public class FriendMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        InfoWindowAdapter {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Context context;
    Marker mMarker;
    public static int snip;
    public static String user_id;
    public static ArrayList<String> useridList, fullnameList, imageList,
            latiList, LongiLIst;
    Button btnBack;
    Bitmap bmImg;
    public ArrayList<Marker> marker;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_map);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        SharedPreferences prefers = this
                .getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_DETAIL", 0);
        user_id = prefers.getString("USER_ID", "");

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.Nearmap);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        GetUserDetailByUserId();
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_marker,
                        null);
                LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();
                snip = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getId().substring(1));
                // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                ImageView imageicon = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.imagemarker);
                // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                for (int i = 0; i < latiList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(
                                imageList.get(snip)).openConnection()
                                .getInputStream());
                        imageicon.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        Picasso.with(FriendMapActivity.this)
                                .load(imageList.get(snip))
                                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                                .into(imageicon);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (FriendMapActivity.this.mMarker != null
                            && FriendMapActivity.this.mMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                     //FriendMapActivity.this.mMarker.hideInfoWindow();

                     FriendMapActivity.this.mMarker.showInfoWindow();
                        for(int i=0;i<marker.size();i++)
                        {
                             FriendMapActivity.this.mMarker.showInfoWindow();
                        }
                    }
                    return null;

            }
        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        // GetUserDetailByUserId();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }
public void GetUserDetailByUserId() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "url of server is here");
                marker = new ArrayList<Marker>();
                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action",
                            "GetUserDetailByUserId"));

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", String
                            .valueOf(5)));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                    .getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    Log.e("get user want to Data", "" + sb.toString());
                    return sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("get user problem", "" + e);
                    return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                useridList = new ArrayList<String>();
                fullnameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
                latiList = new ArrayList<String>();
                LongiLIst = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    if (object.getString("msg").equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject subObj = array.getJSONObject(j);
                            useridList.add(subObj.getString("userid"));
                            fullnameList.add(subObj.getString("fullname"));
                            imageList.add(subObj.getString("image_url"));
                            latiList.add(subObj.getString("latitude"));
                            LongiLIst.add(subObj.getString("longitude"));
                            Log.d("val of userid list:", useridList.toString());
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < latiList.size(); i++) {
                            takeToLocation(new LatLng(
                                    Double.parseDouble(latiList.get(i)),
                                    Double.parseDouble(LongiLIst.get(i))));
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(
                                            new LatLng(Double
                                                    .parseDouble(latiList
                                                            .get(i)), Double
                                                    .parseDouble(LongiLIst
                                                            .get(i))))
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromResource(R.drawable.blue_dot));
                            // // Bitmap circleBitmap =
                            // Bitmap.createBitmap(200,200,
                            // Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            // // Bitmap bmp =
                            // Bitmap.createBitmap(circleBitmap);
                            // // Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);
                            // //
                            // // // paint defines the text color,
                            // // // stroke width, size
                            // // Paint color = new Paint();
                            // // color.setTextSize(12);
                            // // color.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                            // // Bitmap yourBitmap;
                            //
                            //
                            // URL url = new URL(imageList.get(i));
                            // HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
                            // url.openConnection();
                            // conn.setDoInput(true);
                            // conn.connect();
                            // InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                            // bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                            // Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg,
                            // 100, 100, true);
                            // //modify canvas
                            // // canvas1.drawBitmap(
                            // // getCircularBitmapImage(bmImg), 0,0, color);
                            // // canvas1.drawText(fullnameList.get(i), 30, 40,
                            // color);
                            //
                            // //add marker to Map
//                           googleMap.addMarker(new
//                           MarkerOptions().position(new
//                           LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latiList.get(i)),
//                           Double.parseDouble(LongiLIst.get(i))))
//                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCircularBitmapImage(bmImg)))
//                           // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular
//                      
//                           .anchor(0.5f, 1));
                             marker.add(mMarker);

                            mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            mMarker.setTitle("Click Me:");
                            for(i=0;i<marker.size();i++)
                            {
                              mMarker.showInfoWindow();
                            }
                            //mMarker.isInfoWindowShown();
//                          showAllMarker(i);

                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("not a valid user");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("json error in gettripexperience", "" + e);

                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FriendMapActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("");
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                mProgressDialog.show();

            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_marker, null);
        LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();
        // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
        ImageView tvLat = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagemarker);
        // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude

        return v;
    }

    public void takeToLocation(LatLng toBeLocationLatLang) {
        if (toBeLocationLatLang != null) {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    toBeLocationLatLang, 16);
            googleMap.animateCamera(update);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getCircularBitmapImage(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        float r = size / 6f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

            int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
            int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

            Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap
                    .createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
            if (squaredBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                    BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            float r = size / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

            squaredBitmap.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }

        // protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap source,
        // int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        // return getCircularBitmapImage(source);
        // }

        public String getId() {
            return "Glide_Circle_Transformation";
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "circle";
        }

    }
//  function generateInfoWindow(despacedName, despacedTitle, eventTitle, url, date, time){
//      if(!curInfoWindow){
//          curInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:150});
//      }
//      curInfoWindow.setContent("<a class=\"eventLink\" href=\""+url+"\">"+eventTitle+"</a><br><br>"+markerObjects[despacedName].title+"<br>"+date+" at "+time);
//      curInfoWindow.open(map, markerObjects[despacedName]);
//      alert(despacedName+" is "+markerObjects[despacedName]);
//  }

    public void showAllMarker(int pos) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latiList.get(pos)), Double
                        .parseDouble(LongiLIst.get(pos)))).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue_dot));
        mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        if (mMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            Log.d("marker:", mMarker.getId());
        } else {
            mMarker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not good way to show all marker info window at time instead of you show custom user icon as marker for check out this : https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to display all infowindow at a time in map but when I click on one marker,Infowindow on another marker hides how I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to implement this code**

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var markerPosn = new GLatLng(place["posn"][0], place["posn"][1]);
    map.openInfoWindowHtml(markerPosn ,buildPlaceInfoHtml(place),{maxWidth:275});
});
```

You can refer from this link also http://www.aaronkjackson.com/2010/06/how-to-show-an-infowindow-for-multiple-markers-using-google-maps-v3/

I hope this might be help to u.